# How can you reduce/limit bandwidth during scraping of large images?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm to download about 10 million images and after a small experiment of downloading the first 1000 I noticed each takes ~4.5 seconds (which maybe could be slightly sped-up with `multiprocessing.Pool`s) but the biggest problem is that the average image size is ~2400x2400 at ~2.2MB. I can resize them as soon as they are downloaded, but the main bottleneck (currently) is internet bandwidth. Is there a way to download the images directly at a lower resolution?

Sample dummy code:

```
import requests

resp = requests.get("some_url.jpg")
with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Reducing

Unless there are other files with lower resolution available → no. Unless there is some kind of API or basically anything on the server you want to download the file(image) from that modifies it *on the server* before sending the content back as a response.

What you can try though is to check if the website supports `gzip` or other compression and ensure you download the response compressed first, e.g. with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140223/5994041) and then decompress before saving the file e.g. with [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/gzip.html) or [`zlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zlib.html).

For enforcing try to use specific [headers](https://serverfault.com/a/56707/503522) such as `Accept-Encoding`.

## Limiting

Make a simple counter for the data (you can count the bytes while processing or [after you download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591957/5994041)) and if you don't want to reach e.g. more than 100MB per 5 minutes or something, then just put `time.sleep()` for each 100MB chunk downloaded.

#### Minor notes

`Thread` will not help you with parallelizing the work, use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) or likes to *really* split the work to multiple processes so that you get from (random numbers) e.g. 100 files per process per 1 minute base to 400 files downloaded with 4 processes at the same time downloading 100 files each.